# Showing high voted questions of today and last days

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently it is possible in *Questions* and *Unanswered* view to filter for high voted questions which is fine but in most cases you just find stuff that is sorta finished. What I would like to propose is to implement a new filter where the questions are ordered by date as primary key and by highest vote as secondary key. This way it would be possible to find higher quality questions that are buried in all the low quality questions that I see when I use the *newest* view. If there are already possibilites to find new high quality questions please let me know :)

Comment: Well, you can look for [high voted unanswered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) which aren't "finished."  Is that what you mean?